# RTL8152B Ethernet PHY heating up

Tags: ethernet, phy

We are using RTL8152B ethernet to USB PHY for one of our projects, After debugging the board I found the IC to be abnormally warm even when there is no network traffic. I probed using the Multimeter and found that pin 12 which is connected to decaps 41 and 42(in the schematic) showed 0.5V but should have reported 1.05V voltage according to the datasheet, to rule out cap failure I removed it and checked the resistance and it was showing 39ohms which wasn't the case in other boards. I did some digging and found out some useful links which I have included in this post.

After reading those sites I thought maybe because of the wrong schematic the IC has failed but I'm not certain. I want to know whether I have connected the center tap and diff pairs properly i.e. pulling those lines to 3.3V. page 17 of the guideline doc says that PHY side CT pins are connected to cap and 0 ohm which is DNP but in my schematic, it's pulled to 3.3V. Please do note that we have a POE block too, I have a crude understanding that CT pins are used for power delivery. But the board with the issues doesn't have POE block populated. On another Chinese forum, someone mentioned that removing the pull-up on the CT line reduced current consumption. I want to know whether the schematic is wrong and is the PHY current mode line driver or voltage mode and what's the role of the ct pin in driving the signals.
If someone could shed some light on this issue I would be grateful.

Thanks in advance

[Layou guideline](http://www.jfd-ic.com/Documents/RTL8152B(N)_Layout.PDF)

[Chinese blog](https://blog.csdn.net/zlllg/article/details/80008404)

[image: Schematic]

[image: RJ45 Schematic]

[Datasheet of PHY](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/Realtek-Semicon-RTL8152B-VB-CG_C50656.pdf)

[RJ45 magnetics](https://belfuse.com/resources/drawings/magneticsolutions/dr-mag-si-52003-f.pdf)

Comment: "*which wasn't the case in other boards*" - so you have other boards that are OK then, yes?

Comment: yes, I have a few of them, they are warm to touch not blazing hot like this one, Also voltage on those caps is 1.05V as it should be.

Comment: Just swap out the chip.

Comment: It's in the assembly house for replacing the phy chip, Just want to know why it happened and if the schematic is wrong and it's causing the phy chip to behave like this.